# why when add new extension to file more than 5 litter and delete it, remove one letter from original extension python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, module, operating-system

This line to add new extension

```
os.rename(file_name,file_name + ".test12")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJf03.jpg)

this line to delete new extension

```
os.rename(file_name, file_name.strip(".test12"))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKpl8.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

because that's not what strip() does. it doesn't remove a string, but characters from both sides of the string. in your example it didn't remove anything from the left because it is the character 'f' and you gave: '.', 't', 's', '1', '2'. from the right it removed all the characters until it encountered the 'x' and stopped. 
for this specific need, use replace()

```py
file_name = 'file.txt.test12'
print(file_name)
print(file_name.strip('.test12'))
print(file_name.strip('.test12x'))  # added 'x' as well just to learn
print(file_name.replace('.test12', ''))
```

Output:

```sh
file.txt.test12
file.tx
fil
file.txt
```